# My app not run when i install firebase_messaginh & firebase_core Dependency

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

after install when i can run the app performing restart but app not run and that process end.

1. how i cnt solve it.for firebase messaging.
2. i also add flutter_local_notification dependency but not working when generate refresh token so app is cresh and runing process can end. process can not move ahed.
3. how we can solve the problem and give a local notification.

- **Bad ** App Not Install .

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed description of what's causing the error ? Is there a stack trace from the console describing your error ?